# Display only a part of a string

Tags: informix, 4gl

I'm selecting an email address but I don't want to display the full email. Only the part before the '@'. How can I cut it. I know how to display only certain amount of characters or numbers. But how do I specify to display only till the '@' symbol.

Thank you.

Comment: There isn't a built-in function to do the job, but it is not hard to write either an I4GL function that analyses one character at a time, or to write a C function that's callable from I4GL that does the job.  I've done both, though not this millennium.

Comment: What about the CHARINDEX  mentioned by RET?

Comment: [CHARINDEX()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0294.htm?lang=en) is available in SQL in some versions of IDS.  It will work, but involves a round trip to the database to get the answer, whereas an I4GL function will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Informix SQL have the [`CHARINDEX()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0294.htm%23ids_sqs_0294) function which can be used to isolate where the '@' symbol appears:

```
SELECT LEFT(email_addr, CHARINDEX('@', email_addr)-1)
```

CHARINDEX() will return 0 if not found, otherwise the ordinal position of the located string. My testing found that `LEFT()` doesn't complain about being passed 0 or -1, so it's safe to execute this as is, you don't have to verify that you get something back from `CHARINDEX()` first.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ex1
(
  email_addr VARCHAR(60)
) WITH NO LOG;

INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES ('ret@example.com.au');
INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES ('emdee@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES ('unknown');
INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES ('@bademail');

SELECT LEFT(email_addr, CHARINDEX('@', email_addr)-1) FROM ex1
```

... produces:

```
(expression)

ret
emdee


5 row(s) retrieved.
```

If you have an older version of Informix that doesn't support `CHARINDEX()`, you'll be forced to iterate through the string character by character, until you find the '@' symbol.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm going to try it out soon. Can I use this while I'm selecting other columns? Like I'm selecting fname, lname, and email_addr.  Can I do select fname, lname, left(email_addr, charindex.........)

Comment: Yes, there's no reason why not, it's just a derived column.